# How to add new non-standard field to event object in Full Calendar

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, fullcalendar

How do you add a non-standard event field to Full Calendar?

I already read the other questions about this - their answers just say the same thing as the [documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) which is incomplete

Comment: Can you give an example of a non-standard event field? Or maybe an example of what you are trying to add to the event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Simple concept) - One way to do it, if you already have a field created in the database, is to just place that field in the array from your rails page. On the JS side, use [eventRender](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/) and append it to whatever element you desire.

Comment: could you provide a snibbet example? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just read this in other question, but i didn't test.

add this callback

```
eventRender: function( event, element, view ) 
    { 
        //redo the title to include the description
        element.find(".fc-event-title").html(event.title + ": <span>" + event.description + "</span>");
    },
```

[jQuery Calendar : how to add clickable events on particular dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008454/jquery-calendar-how-to-add-clickable-events-on-particular-dates)