# Full calender delete an event

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar

I am looking to delete an event from my full calender via a event that confirmation dialog box when clicked.  I am also looking to use a form(with text-boxes) to save values into my calender.  I have read the documentation but I do not know how to implement, where to place and how to use functions such as:

```
.fullCalendar( 'removeEventSource', source )
```

The calender is nearly fully implemented just need these last few functions.

here is the code, simply copy and paste it into notepad to run it and see.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href='../fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='../fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
<script src='../jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script>
<script src='../jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js'></script>
<script src='../fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

var equip = document.getElementById('equipment').value;
var size = document.getElementById('size').value;
var surface = document.getElementById('surface').value;
var orderNumber = document.getElementById('orderNumber').value;
var responsible = document.getElementById('responsible').value;

        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();

        var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            select: function(start, end, allDay) {
                var equipment = document.getElementById('equipment');
                var title = prompt('Title');
                if (title && surface) {
                    calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                        {

                            title: title,
                            start: start,
                            end: end,
                            allDay: allDay,
                            description: "ga",
                            backgroundColor: 'red'
                        },

                        true // make the event "stick"
                    );
                }
                else if(title){
                    calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                        {

                            title: title,
                            start: start,
                            end: end,
                            allDay: allDay
                        },

                        true // make the event "stick"
                    );
                }
                calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
            },

            eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

                alert("Equipment: " + equip + "\nSize: " + size + 
                "\nRequired on Surface: " + surface + 
                "\nWork Order Number: " + orderNumber + 
                "\nResponsible: " + responsible);
                var r=confirm("Press a button");
                if (r==true)
                  {

                  }
                else
                  {
                  x="You pressed Cancel!";
                  }
                // change the border color just for fun
                $(this).css('border-color', 'red');

            },
//          eventMouseover: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
//              if(surface)
//              {
//              // change the border color just for fun
//                  $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
//              }

//          },

            editable: true,
            events: [
                {
                    title: 'Test event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, 28),
                    color: 'yellow',
                    url: 'http://google.com/'
                }
            ]

    });

    });

</script>
<style>

    body {
        margin-top: 40px;
        text-align: left;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
        }

    #calendar {
        width: 1000px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<align="right">

<FORM>
Equipment: <input type='text' id='equipment' /> <br />
Size: <input type='text' id='size' /> <br />
Required on Surface: <input type='text' id='surface' /> <br />
Work Order Number: <input type='text' id='orderNumber' /> <br />
Responsible: <input type='text' id='responsible' /> <br />
<div id='calendar'></div>
<FORM>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I answered something similar a while back. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008454/jquery-calendar-how-to-add-clickable-events-on-particular-dates/12009331#12009331. Might apply here too.

Comment: I have seen your fiddle before however that is using date picker and that does not allow for multiple events on a single date.

Comment: Well, doesn't it show how to accomplish what you want?

Comment: Spoke too soon I think so Ill comment again soon

Answer (score 0):

```
var r=confirm("Press a button");

if (r==true)
{
    deleteevent(eventid,startdatetime,enddatetime)//when r is true write a function to make a server call to delete the event and save it in DB
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');// remove events
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', pEvents);//add events
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');// re render the events
}
```

thats it, hope this will work.